# Where I can find build.gradle file in order to Add Support Libraries for android in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

they say go to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html and follow steps -->
1- OPEN build.gradle ,
I don't get it , Where I can find this file ?

I was thinking that they might mean the folder which consist of the application that I need the library for , but there is no such file in it

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to switch to Android studio

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use gradle as a build tool, and since google droped the Eclipse support over 2 years ago I suggest you switch to android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse, we dont have provision of build.gradle file, it's only available in Android studio. 
to add support library Using Eclipse follow below steps:

Create a library project based on the support library code:

- Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
- Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path:
- Select File > Import.
- Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
- Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder. For example, if you are adding the cardview project, browse to /extras/android/support/v7/cardview/.
- Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 cardview project, you should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-cardview.
- In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. For example, when creating the v7 cardview project, add the android-support-v7-cardview.jar file to the build path.
- Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.
- In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the cardview project requires you to export the android-support-v7-cardview.jar file.
- Uncheck Android Dependencies.
- Click OK to complete the changes.
- You now have a library project for your selected Support Library that you can use with one or more application projects.
- Add the library to your application project:
- In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
- In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
- In the Library pane, click the Add button.
- Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-cardview.
- In the properties window, click OK.